# Unable to host Ember CLI on Firebase

Tags: firebase, emberfire

I'm unable to host my app on Firebase, and I'm not sure how I could fix it. I'm using Ember Cli with Ember Data.

> Uncaught Error: Could not find module `emberfire/initializers/emberfire` imported from `nutella/initializers/emberfire`

nutella/initializers/emberfire doesn't exist in my folders. However I have it at nutella/node_modules/emberfire/app/initializers/emberfire.js and also on  nutella/node_modules/emberfire/addon/initializers/emberfire.js.

What should I do?!

**Addition:**

I am using     "ember-cli": "^0.2.3",
    "emberfire": "^1.4.4",

Dependencies on bower.js:

```
"ember": "1.11.1",
"ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
"ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
"ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
"ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
"ember-qunit": "0.3.1",
"ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
"ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
"jquery": "^1.11.1",
"loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
"qunit": "~1.17.1",
"foundation": "~5.5.0",
"firebase": "^2.1.0",
"emberfire": "~1.4.4"

"firebase-simple-login": "~1.6.4"
```

Comment: This is actually two questions, which will make grading the answers and determining the "best" answer a bit schizophrenic. Please consider revising. The first is a config error that could probably be solved by simply searching your project for `Firebase` and correcting the incorrect app name references to `nutella`. The second looks like you have incorrectly installed emberfire.

Comment: Please list the version of ember-cli and emberfire that your project is using. It seems like you might be using a very old version, pre 0.1.12. Also, please list your dependencies listed in bower.json

Comment: Thank you! I listed the dependencies. I tried searching the word "Firebase" and changing to nutella but it did not work.

Comment: And I've divided up the questions into two, like you suggested. Here's the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813560/namespace-firebase-already-declared

Answer (score 2):

For some reason this worked when I changed the file name in the app-name/initializer folder to emberfire.js. There must've been some code that specified that the name needs to be emberfire.js.