# Namespace "Firebase" already declared

Tags: firebase, emberfire

I cannot find for my life why it's saying that I've declared the namespace twice.

The error message is:

> Uncaught Error: Namespace "Firebase" already declared.

I saw that people having this error named their app 'emberfire' or 'firebase'. I named my app 'nutella' so I don't know why it's complaining about the namespace.

I tried searching for the word "Firebase" and here's the result:

/Users/sunoceansand/nutella/app/adapters/application.js:

```
1  import config from '../config/environment';

2: import Firebase from 'firebase';
3: import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firebase';
4  
5: export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({
6:   firebase: new Firebase(config.firebase)
7  });
8
```

/Users/sunoceansand/nutella/app/initializers/session.js:

```
4  var session = Ember.Object.extend({
5  
6:  addFirebaseCallback: function() {
7       var session = this;
8
```

/Users/sunoceansand/nutella/app/serializers/nutella.js:

```
1  import DS from 'ember-data';
2  
3: export default DS.FirebaseSerializer.extend({
4  });
5
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved when I uninstalled an addon that I had randomly installed.